# Jacoco and jetty maven plugin gets 0% coverage in SonarQube

Tags: jetty, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am trying to get the IT coverage report in my project using jacoco & Jetty. I'm running my integration tests against jetty (using the maven plugin). I have done the setup. Here is my POM

```
<profile>
        <id>quality-check</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*IT*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IT*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <!--  ... //Whatever you need to configure on your integration test, if any.-->
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/*Test*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-unit-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/*Test*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <propertyName>jacoco.agent.itArgLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-integration-test</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-jetty</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                                <goal>run-forked</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                                <daemon>true</daemon>
                                <waitForChild>false</waitForChild>
                                <maxStartupLines>200</maxStartupLines>
                                <jvmArgs>${jacoco.agent.itArgLine} -Djetty.port=${integration.tests.jetty.port}</jvmArgs>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-jetty</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                        <httpConnector>
                            <port>${integration.tests.jetty.port}</port>
                        </httpConnector>
                        <contextXml>../integrationTest/jetty_context.xml</contextXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

jetty_context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"     "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/SAI</Set>
  <Set name="extraClasspath">../testResources/src/test/resources</Set>
</Configure>
```

the setup is done base on the post [Jacoco and jetty maven plugin gets 0% coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645713/jacoco-and-jetty-maven-plugin-gets-0-coverage). But no luck yet.

The coverage is 0%

in the log I can see an error:

```
[INFO] Forked process starting
[INFO] Forked process startup errors
```

Can some one help me please? Do I have to do anything else.

Comment: Do you have jacoco.exec file?

Comment: Why are you running `jetty:stop` on `pre-integration-test` phase?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt,  I just use it to stop any stray process that has been running since before.

Comment: @arseniyandru yes I have the file.

Comment: Goals in an execution are not guaranteed to execute in the order you specified, Maven is free to execute those goals in any order within that same phase.  (think of it this way: goals are a Set, not a List)

Comment: Move your "cleanup" `jetty:stop` to a different phase.  Would suggest the `pre-clean` phase (of the [clean lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle)) or the `validate` phase of the default lifecycle.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, Indeed a good idea.

Comment: I have managed to fix the problem "Forked process startup errors" by changing the port. Now its saying "Forked process started", But still no luck with the coverage. Any help/ suggestion ?